# How does one calculate the area of a set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

The set is $M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y|\leq 1\}$.

**Question:** How do you calculate the area of $M$? More specific, how do you find the bounds of integration?

**Attempt:** I tried to solve the inequality, yielding,
$$
\begin{align*}
(x,y)>0&:x\leq -y+1,y\leq 1&(x,y)<0&:-x\leq y+1\Leftrightarrow x\geq -y-1,y\geq -1\\
\end{align*}
$$
and then the integral
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{J}&=\int_0^1\int_0^{-y+1}\text{d}x\text{d}y-\int_{-1}^0\int_{-y-1}^0\text{d}x\text{d}y=0
.\end{align*}
$$
The solution, however, is $\mathcal{J}'=2$. I presume, the bounds of integration are wrong, thus the solution to the inequality is not correct.

**Edit:** Corrected a typo in the inequality, but did not change integration bounds (see comments).

Comment: It may help to try graphing this if the algebraic method feels unwieldy. If done correctly it should look like a rotated square.

Comment: Well you can't have $y>=1$ in that left inequality (other than y=1 corresponding to x=0).  Neither x nor y can be greater than one unit away from the origin.

Comment: @Gregory Yes, the thing is, I would like to be able to solve it the algebraic way, in case I can't draw the figure.

Comment: The area is a square of length sqrt(2)

Comment: $|x|+|y|\le1$ iff either $0\le x\le1$ and $-(1-x)\le y\le1-x,$ or $-1\le x\le0$ and $-(1+x)\le y\le1+x.$
$\int_{-1}^02(1+x)dx+\int_0^12(1-x)dx=1+1.$

Comment: Your integral covers only the parts of the figure in quadrants $I$ and $III$. The figure also extends into quadrants $II$ and $IV$. And why do you feel that quadrant $III$ must have negative area?

Answer (score 1):

$A=\iint_M \mathrm dx \mathrm dy = 2\int_{-1}^0\mathrm dx \int_0^{1+x} \mathrm dy + 2 \int_0^1 \mathrm dx \int_0^{1-x} \mathrm dy = \dots = 2\dfrac{1}{2} + 2\dfrac{1}{2} = \boxed{2}$.

Figure:

[image]